# Is it possible to define an enum without an explicit type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In an interface I have 10+ (optional) members of which most have a definitive set of possible values, so I'd like to use enums for them. However this requires to define at least 10 new enum types with only very few members (and only used once), so I'd like to define the enums directly in the interface. Therefore, instead of:

```
export interface Options {
    option1?: bool | Option1Enum;
    option2?: bool | Option2Enum;
    option3?: bool | Option3Enum;
    option4?: bool | Option4Enum;
    option5?: bool | Option5Enum;
}
```

I would like kinda implicit enums, say:

```
export interface Options {
    option1?: bool | { option11, option12 };
    option2?: bool | { option21, option22 };
    option3?: bool | { option31, option32, option33 };
    option4?: bool | { option41, option42 };
    option5?: bool | { option51 };
}
```

which doesn't compile. Is there a way to do this kind of enum declaration in Typescript?

In other langugages this is possible, e.g. in C++:

```
  class Options {
  public:
    enum { value1, value2, } enumMember = value1;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution seems to be strings:

```
export interface Options {
    option1?: bool | "option11" | "option12";
    option2?: bool | "option21" | "option22";
    option3?: bool | "option31" | "option32" | "option33";
    option4?: bool | "option41" | "option42";
    option5?: bool | "option51";
}
```

The transpiler ensures only these values can be assigned, which is essentially like an enum would behave.